# Adding extract tool to nautilus (compiled from source code)

Tags: nautilus, compiling, nautilus-extensions

How can add and Extract Zip File tool to nautilus?

I installed nautilus from the standard source code in repository. Now:

[image]

?

I remember there was a `extract here` selection in this menu before installing nautilus from source code.

Comment: What version of nautilus are you using? It seems you have tweaked nautilus which might have caused this, since it is available by default. What is the change you have made?

Comment: It is the last standard nautilus for Ubuntu 13.10 from repository. But it is compiled and installed normally from sources and is not installed from a deb file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the **"Extract Here"** and **"Compress..."** menus are displayed when the [File Roller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Roller) utility is installed. (Nautilus source code check for the file-roller).

> File Roller is an archive manager for the GNOME environment.  This
> means that you can create and modify archives; view the content of an
> archive; view and modify a file contained in the archive; extract
> files from the archive.

You can install it with:

- `sudo apt-get install file-roller`

**Nautilus without file-roller:**

[image]

**Nautilus with file-roller installed:**

[image]

#### Edit:

Do to nautilus was installed from source with the prefix **/usr/local** instead **/usr**. the package **file-roller** install the *libnautilus-fileroller.so* under /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0. To solve this issue you can try the following:

**1)** Create a softlink to the extension in /usr/local.

- `cd /usr/local/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0`
- `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libnautilus-fileroller.so .`

**2)** Make sure the softlink was created.

- `ls -l /usr/local/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libnautilus-fileroller.so`

Finally you can Logout & Loging to see the changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried `sudo apt-get install file-roller ` but it is already installed. It may be incompatible with the compiled version if it is really  the nautilus extract tool.

Comment: 13.10 and I have not updated anything from the date of original post above. I see 'Move to wastebasket' in compiled version while in deb one it was 'Move to trash'. It seems the source code is not the same as deb.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: I think you installed from source with make install with the prefix /usr/local. please check if you have the extension "libnautilus-fileroller.so" under the directory "/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0". then you can make a link to the directory where you have installed nautilus from source eg: "/usr/local/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0"

Comment: `libnautilus-fileroller.so` exists. I installed noramly as is  explained in a INSTALL file in source code directory. I don't know exactly what else I should do. The source code version is `nautilus-3.8.2` for me.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus: You can check my edit to see if its works.